# Take data in XML format within the variable with LinQ

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

"Orderedtabs " How can I get the data in a variable ?
XML data within the picture I showed you I need to buy separately.
Then I show them(Nick,Score) the ListView.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbvFB.png)

```
        XElement root = XElement.Load(dosyaYolu);
        var orderedtabs = root.Elements("Oyuncu")
                              .OrderByDescending(xtab => (int)xtab.Element("Score"))
                              .ToList().Take(10);


 // string ID = orderedtabs[i].ID ?? 
 //How can I access this manner or otherwise?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Attribute property of Element i.e.

```
foreach(var tab in orderedtabs)
{
   var ID = tab.Attribute("ID").ToString();
}
```

or you can do it in query itself:

```
var orderedtabs = root.Elements("Oyuncu").OrderByDescending(xtab => (int)xtab.Element("Score")).Attributes("ID").ToList().Take(10);
```

Comment: var ID = tab.Attribute("ID").ToString(); not working , Attribute("ID") underlines. tab.PreviousAttribute and tab.NextAttribute  coming

Comment: I have mentioned 2 ways of getting attribute values above. I think you are trying to use Attribute property even after applying Attributes in the LINQ query. you don't need to use Attribute property now as you already have got attributes. Now you can simply get value using ID = tab.ToString() in the loop. And if you haven't applied Attributes property in LINQ query, you can follow first approach of looping and then getting Attribute Property.

Comment: Thank you so much. But can I ask you one more question?


      foreach (var tab in orderedtabs)
            {
                var ID = tab.Attribute("ID").ToString(); 
                var Nick = tab.Element("Nick").ToString();
                var Score = tab.Element("Score").ToString();
            }

The value of variable;

ID => ID="2" 
Nick => <Nick> Mehmet </Nick>
Score => <Score> 1500 </Score> 

as it seems.

Do you have to get these variables as possible?

ID =>2
Nick => Mehmet
Score => 1500

Comment: Welcome. You can use 'Value' property to get only the values and not the tags i.e. tab.Attribute("ID").Value.ToString(), tab.Element("Nick").Value etc. Remember to mark as answer if it helped.